# R curves:part of the curve is not displayed

Tags: r, plot, histogram

[image]

I tried to add a curve to the histogram created by hist() in advance, while the peak of the curve cannot be fully displayed (maybe because the height of the histogram is not enough to show the whole curve)
Is there a way to adjust the size of the histogram to the height of the curve **without using ggplot**?

Comment: ?par perhaps. Also add sample data using `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your code, so I don't know what you're doing, but you could try adjusting the range of your y axis by adding a ylim to your hist, e.g.

```
hist(data, breaks=whatever, ylim=c(0, maximal_value))
```